# HTML not running

Tags: html

There is are all my HTML below .
Theses are errors I got. I see red.

```html
<p>
  Mary defeated Serena Williams in the U.S. 
  Open women's singles final and became 
  <strong>first Canadian to win a tennis Grand Slam title.</strong>
</p>
<br>
<source srcset="http://www.cbc.ca/sports”/hr2>

    <hr />
        <h2>
            <p>Mary Wins U.S. Open</p>
        </h2><br>
        <p> Mary defeated Serena Williams in the U.S. 
            Open women's singles final and became <strong>first Canadian to win a tennis Grand Slam title.</strong></p><br>
            <source srcset="http://www.cbc.ca/sports”/hr2>
        <img src="Mary.jpg" alt="photo of Mary" width ="400" height="300"/>
        <br>
        <p>Photo by  Elsa/Getty Images <a hret="
            https://www.cbc.ca/sports/tennis/us-open-tennis-final-women-andreescu-1.5274870"
        </p>
        <hr>
```

Comment: *Theses are errors I got.* What errors? *I see red* Me too sometimes, but I don't understand what you mean by that in this context.

Comment: For one, you should use `"` on the third line instead of `”`.

Comment: OK: your code has many errors.  There are lots of resources available to you that will help you a) identify HTML errors in your markup, and b) look up how to correct your errors.  Consider starting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Debugging_HTML or here: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Answer (score 0):

Both source tags have errors. It's a typo. You need to move the second double quote to the end of the line. Use this:

```
<source srcset="http://www.cbc.ca/sports/hr2">
```